# auto.arima extracts different p, d, q in Window and Linux

Tags: linux, r

We are trying to run auto.arima in Linux to speed up processing time . Although it saved time to run the process, it yielded different forecast value for few products (we got similar results for many of the products) that did not match with the results we got from Window. We used following syntex in both Window and Linux:

```
fit=auto.arima(data series)
ff <- forecast(fit, h=6)
plot(forecast(fit, h=6))
```

To elaborate the problem let's mention that the two OS extracted different p, d, q for these products. Please help us to understand the differences.

Comment: Can you include a small example of `data series` that gives you this result?

Comment: Also, before jumping to the conclusion that its the OS, you should at least make sure your environments are otherwise the same.  Post your sessionInfo() and options().